# is && enough for tail recursion?

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

does the .net compiler knows to produce a tail recursion fromt the followin code?
(meaning it knows that no backtracking should be made, because of the `&&` ?)

```
public bool DeleteLocation(Guid locationId)
{

    return ((_mLocationDal.Save(locationRes) != null) && 
             locationRes.ChildrenIds.Aggregate(true, 
                        (succeededSoFar, next) => succeededSoFar && 
                                                  DeleteLocation(next)));
}
```

Comment: This is a potentially interesting question, but all of the answers so far seem to be fixating on the fact that the *compiler* doesn't perform these operations, but rather the CLR's JIT compiler. If that's what you're asking about, you should consider editing the question to remove erroneous references to the compiler.

Answer (score 5):

[The C# compiler doesn't emit tail calls at all](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/166013/c-compiler-should-optimize-tail-calls) AFAIK. [The JIT of the CLR may discover and apply tail calls however.](http://blogs.msdn.com/shrib/archive/2005/01/25/360370.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Even if C# compiler supported tail recursion optimization (which it does not) it wouldn't detect it in case of your program, because `DeleteLocation` does not call itself directly. A functor that it uses calls `DeleteLocation`, but that is not enough to optimize a recursive tail call.

On a side note, `All` provides a more compact replacement for `Aggregate` in your case:

```
public bool DeleteLocation(Guid locationId) {
        return (_mLocationDal.Save(locationRes) != null) && 
            locationRes.ChildrenIds.All(next => DeleteLocation(next));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Boolean expressions are evaluated lazily; e.g. in `A && B`, `B` is never evaluated if `A` is false. This is why it's safe to do things like `if (thing != null && thing.DoSomething())`.

Answer (score 1):

The C# compiler doesn't support the tail recursion at all, if by "tail" you mean calling methods with the CIL's `.tail` prefix which does not leave a frame on the stack.